# How to select outermost vertices in a shape like this?

Tags: mesh, vertices

I have a mesh, in the shape of a geographical state, which I created (rather crudely) following these steps:

1. Keeping an image in the background,
2. Adding a plane with *1000x1000 subdivision* over it
3. Selecting vertices which overlap the state image manually
4. Separating them to form a mesh

The end result looks like this:

Object Mode:

[image]

Edit mode (Vertices):

[image]

My question is: **How can I select the outermost vertices to form a plane mesh with the given shape?**

I would like to be able to bevel this shape (and others like it) to represent some sort of data in a WebGL application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De-select all and then select one of the innermost vertices in vertex-select mode. Go to *Select > Select Similar > Amount of Adjacent Faces*. This will select all vertices with 4 adjacent faces (ie, all those 'inner' vertices).

Next just *Select > Invert* to invert the selection so you have all the *outer* vertices (and so Edges) selected.

Comment: Not sure if it works here, but might involve less steps to select non manifold

Comment: Good spot @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - yes - that seems to work.

Comment: lol, Non manifold was the first thing I tried... didn't think it worked, realize now I  just cant see it in solid mode.

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick!

Answer (score 9):

**Select Boundary Loop.**

[image]

First, <kbd>A</kbd> Select All

Then in <kbd>2</kbd> Edge select mode,

*`Select > Select Loops > Select Boundary Loop`*

At this stage an option is to <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Separate Selected, to make the boundary edge a new object... or

[image]

dissolve (or delete) internal verts to end up with one big ngon state

<kbd>1</kbd> Vert select mode,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> *`Select > Invert`*

Then <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> Dissolve Vertices.

Comment: I tried that option (Boundary Loop) first and it didn't work.... However, I've just re-tried and it appears to work on the current selection - so you have to make sure the whole mesh is selected first.

Comment: Cheers will add that.

Comment: Thanks, this one works same as the previous answer, wish I could accept both!

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava cheers. The elephant in the room is the comment by Duarte, can simply _`Select > Select by Trait > Non Manifold`_  Out of curiosity which state is it?

Comment: I guess that would be shortest, might try it out. The state is `Maharashtra, India`

Answer (score 4):

I usually select one of the edges, and use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>,  *Select Similar > Amount of Faces Around an Edge*.

[image]

It's the same as @Rich Sedman's, but using edges, and the other way round.

(Just hit Keyboard <kbd>1</kbd> to convert the selection to vertices)

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick as well